# Disassembly of a `int fn(); fn();` vs `int fn(void); fn();`

Tags: c, assembly

On 86_64:

```
void x()
{
    void y(void);
    y();
}
```

disassembles to

```
x:
        jmp     y
```

whereas

```
void x()
{
    void y();
    y();
}
```

disassembles to

```
x:
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        jmp     y
```

IOW, why does eax need to be zeroed before making a prototypeless call?

Comment: What level of optimization did you specify?

Comment: Because without a prototype it may be a varargs function, and for those the sysv ABI requires `al` to contain number of SSE registers used (zero here).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler 3 of course :) https://godbolt.org/g/gseo2H

Comment: @Jester: that sounds plausible — but it's defensive. You can't legitimately call a varargs function without a proper prototype ending with ellipsis `int y(…, ...)` in scope, so `y` can't be a varargs.   Officially.  Funnier things have been known.

Comment: @Jester Thanks. I knew it was here somewhere. :)

Comment: I'll observe, slightly tongue-in-cheek, that I'd be happier if the functions were declared to return `void` since they don't return a value.

Comment: @Jester: Even if it is a varargs function, the compiler is not required to account for that. Calling varargs function without seeing a *prototype* has always been *undefined behavior* in standard C. C compiler is not required to accomodate for the fact that `fun` can potentially be varargs function. If some compiler does that, it is a peculiarity of specific implementation, not explainable in any way by rules of standard C language.